# Cloudcode Mongodb with Geopoint

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

We have migrate our database to MongoLab via Heroku but now our cloudcode doesn't work anymore.

After looking the code, it seems all the features of Geopoint doesn't work with MongoDB.

Here is our code:

```
var userGeoPoint = new Parse.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
var query = new Parse.Query("User");
query.near("location", userGeoPoint);
query.limit(10);
query.find({
  success: function(placesObjects) {
    console.log("yes");
  },
  error:function(status) {
    console.log(status);
  }
});
```

And here is the answer:

```
Result: {"code":1,"message":"internal error"}
```

Any help will save my life...

Thanks!

Comment: I had this same problem and was getting the same errors. It turns out my MongoLab credentials were incorrect. I was using my actual MongoLab login and password instead of my database user login and password. e.g. `mongodb://databaseuser:password123@ds6666.mongolab.com:6666/myapp`. Not sure if this would fix your problem however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I created a new db user and all the other requests work.
Could it be related to my plan on MongoLab, I'm using the sandbox for now?

Comment: I'm not too sure, I'm using sandbox as well and haven't had any troubles so far.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue originally but I fixed it with set failIndexKeyTooLong=false. Sandbox from mLab doesn't support this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to add this line once we get out of the sandbox ;)